# Using geocode function with ArcPy cursors?

Tags: arcpy, geocoding, cursor

How do I use a cursor with a geocode address function?

I want to be able to:

1. read from a table
2. only geocode addresses(from table1) whose street number is not 0 using a cursor
3. then update a master table with the results from the geocode

---

```
# only try to geocode those addresses whose first street number digit is not zero

  # Select the first char of the street number in the aRecord.ADDRESS1 field
    MyStr = "!aRecord.ADDRESS1!.split(" ")[0]"
    if MyStr != '0':
        address_table = "table1"
        address_locator = r"http://myservername/ArcGIS/rest/services/Composite_Locator/GeocodeServer"
        geocode_result = "geocode_result"

        #Add XY fields and calculate XY
        sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4100)
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(geocode_result, ["SHAPE@XY", "X", "Y"], "", sr) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                row[1] = row[0][0]
                row[2] = row[0][1]

                # geocode is successful only if it returns a valid X (and Y)

            if (row[1] > 0.0):
                cursor.updateRow(row)
                Row_tobe_Inserted.X = row[1]
                Row_tobe_Inserted.Y = row[2]
                XY_Method = "Geocode"

            del row, cursor
    else:
        print "There are no records to be geocoded"
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?